# Alternative to Perl's POD Documentation in Other Languages?

Tags: documentation, perl

Perl has this really cool documentation method that makes documenting really easy. It's called [POD (Plain Old Documentation)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html). Here is an example:

```
=head1 NAME

Example::Module - an example

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    use Example::Module;
    my $object = Example::Module->new();
    print $object->as_string;

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Just an example.

=head2 Methods

=over 12

=item C<new>

Returns a new My::Module object.

=item C<as_string>

Returns a stringified representation of
the object. This is mainly for debugging
purposes.

=back

=head1 LICENSE

This is released under the Artistic 
License. See L<perlartistic>.

=head1 AUTHOR

Dynamic 

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<perlpod>

=cut
```

The output of this would be in HTML, like [this example on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~copperly/Perl-Tutorial-0.001/lib/Perl/Tutorial/HelloWorld.pod) (not what I wrote). Cool right!

So is there a method similar to POD in which a developer can put there documentation inside of the code itself, without it being a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JavaDocs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) are very similar to this. They are comments but they are a special form of comment that are then compiled to produce documents that look like the official Java documentation.

Both JavaDoc and POD are examples of "Documentation Generators" of which there are many. Wikipedia has a good sized [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators) for a variety of platforms and languages.

Comment: I would like to point out that there has been at least [one published book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) written in a [variant of POD](http://p3rl.org/Pod::PseudoPod). [*](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/07/free-tools-for-free-books.html)